# Cyclic dependence in include files

Tags: c++

I have a few data types declared in a file "`mtm_ex4.h`" which I want (actually need) to use in a "`fan.h`" file.

The problem is that I'm using some other data types in "`mtm_ex4.h`" which are declared in "fan.h"

How can I solve this cyclic dependence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are "allowed" to create a ***forward declaration header*** for it?  Such headers (e.g. `<iosfwd>`) declare types, constants etc. that allow some/all of the full header's (e.g. `<iostream>`) functionality to be used, though some types may be incomplete and only usable via pointer or reference.  It's far preferable for such headers to be included from the existing header to ensure they stay in sync, and for at least those things that don't introduce unwanted dependencies (i.e. need supporting `#includes`, couple clients to inline implementation for private members/function bodies), to ensure a single authoritative place of definition.  If you're working in a team or company, the team maintaining the main header should be maintaining the forward declaration header too.

Still, you're clearly working with restrictions so may have to pick the lesser of evils....

Answer (score 2):

You can make something like common.h file, which would have declared types that are used both by mtm_ex4.h and fan.h, and make both of these files dependent from common.h.

Comment: @Doppelganger So why don't you put those kind of crucial details in your question?

Comment: @Doppelganger so you just keep people guessing for fun? Nice.

Comment: Can you edit fan.h file? If you can, place everything that is common in fan.h file and the rest of in a new file, that would be dependent from both mtm_ex4.h and fan.h. If you can't however edit fan.h file, it means that you probably shouldn't use this library at all.